# Reducing the rows of a dataframe by adding observed values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have experimental data for a number of microscope slides. For each slide I have taken a number of photographic images, and on each image I have a number of specimens. I would like to know show many specimens I have for each slide:

eg: **On slide 0, I have four specimens in total** (three in image 1, one in image2):

```
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import seaborn as sns

data = {'Slide' :      [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,    9,9,],
        'Image' :      [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,  2,2,2,    1,7],
        'Specimen' :   [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,  1,1,1,    1,1],
        'Foci' :       [8,9,7,9,6,9,7,9,6,  6,7,6,    9,6]}

df = DataFrame(data, columns=['Slide','Image','Specimen','Foci'])
df
```

[image]

I can get part way to an answer, but this is not quite what I need, as I still need to add up the specimen numbers for each slide:

```
df.groupby(['Slide','Image']).max()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The groupby feature allows you to essentially "pivot" the results like you would in excel:

```
df = df.groupby(['Slide','Image']).Specimen.nunique()
```

The .nunique() function will give you the number of unique values per image per slide. You can then use .reset_index() on this series to convert it back to a dataframe.

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

df
    Slide   Image   Specimen
0   0       1       3
1   0       2       1
2   9       1       1
3   9       7       1
```

If you then want to find just the sum of values by slide you can use one final groupby:

```
df =  df.groupby('Slide').sum()['Specimen']
df
Slide
0    4
9    2
```

Comment: Nearly there! How would I then SUM the Specimen numbers for each slide, to give me the answer that slide0 has four specimens and slide 9 has two specimens?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the [`.nunique()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html) `Specimen` for each `.groupby(['Slide', 'Image')` like so:

```
uniques = df.groupby(['Slide', 'Image'])['Specimen'].nunique()
```

Then you can `.sum()` for each slide:

```
uniques.groupby(level='Slide').sum()
```

to get:

```
Slide
0    4
9    2
```

Comment: I see that my OP isn't very clear, sorry!  IN the original data frame the Specimen value refers to the specimen identifier, and is not a specimen count. So, slide0 image1 has three specimens (specimen 1, 2 and 3) and slide 0 image2 has one specimen (identified as specimen 1 in the dataframe). So, for slide0 I would like an automatic way to get the value of "4" back, referring to the number of specimens in total, for all the images taken of slide0.   I hope this clarifies the question?!